# How to get domain name of requested user in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, api

I am working on one API where i need to validate requested domains.

So how can i have domain name?

I want domain name like http://google.com if request to my site coming from http://google.com

I have tried all the $_REQUEST global variables but in some i can find ip address in some i can have hosting company name means host. But i want just domain name or sub-domain if it is from.

Comment: tried `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`?

Comment: Yes, but gives error Message: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER

Comment: That shouldn't happen. That element is always set. If there's no referer, it returns `NULL`.

Comment: If this is an AJAX API, you should use `HTTP_ORIGIN` to get the client domain.

Comment: I need to do it in php or CodeIgniter only

Comment: How is your API meant to be used? I mean, just because someone uses an API, it doesn't mean that the request comes from a website/server with a valid domain.